# Check what parameters are set in a concise way - PHP

Tags: php, url, parameters

I need to get many parameters from a url with different names and check if they are set. (their value doesn't necessarily matter).

```
https://example.com?one=true&two=true&three=true      etc.
```

The problem is that in what I want to do, any of them could be set or not.

So I need help of a way to grab which of them are in the url and are set in a clean way, and preferably stored in different variables matching the name of the parameters, instead of having multiple `$_GET` and `isset()` lines with `if` statements all over the place.

EDIT: SUBMIT BEING A PARAMETER WHICH WILL ALWAYS BE IN THE URL: I was thinking this could just be done using a foreach loop.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  $key = $value;
  echo $key;
 }
}
```

this will echo out the value of the $key, (which is all i need because then i know it is set), but then i need to get the actual name of what $key is set to.

Thanks

EDIT 2:
I have found out how to do this - all i needed was to get the parameters in the url and know the name of them. Sorry if i had worded it wierdly.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
 foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
 $$value = $key;
 echo $key;
 }
}
```

I found out using variable variables is what i needed (hence the 2 $$)
This gives me, in the end, $key as the name of whatever parameters are in the url, stored in $value which has the same name.

Comment: What should happen when one of them isn't set?

Comment: After you dynamically create a bunch of different variables matching the names of the parameters, have you considered what you'll need to do when it's time to actually use one of those variables?

Comment: I would create an array of expected keys with values set to false (or whatever) , and then merge with $_GET. I would NOT dynamically create variables based on the name. That is potentially going to lead to all sort of issues.

Comment: ok i will try that out

Comment: could i use post instead of get to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to extract all keys from an array and treat them as variables

> Import variables into the current symbol table from an array

Here is a small example:

```
$_GET['var_1'] = 1;
$_GET['var_2'] = 2;
$_GET['var_3'] = '';
extract($_GET);
echo $var_1;
```

Use below code to get empty as well as set keys/values:

```
$newArray = array_filter($_GET);
$sub_key    = array_keys($newArray);
print_r($sub_key); // this will give you all keys that have values

$sub_values = array_values($newArray);
print_r(array_diff($_GET, $sub_values)); // all keys that have empty values
```

Comment: Why the down-votes? Would appreciate the reason and learn from my mistake, if any.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't answer the question. It just makes sure that all the parameters that are provided are not empty, it doesn't validate that the expected parameters are present.

Comment: Well, OP wants _stored in different variables matching the name of the parameters_ and that can be achieved using `extract()`, right? And second condition checks, if any of the array element is empty or not set.

Comment: You missed the first part of the question _I need to get many parameters from a url with different names and **check if they are set**_

Comment: That first part was helpful thank you, but I do not know which parameters are set, only which of them could be - would a solution to this be that I  `$_GET` all possible parameters and then only the one's which are present will be saved to the array?

Comment: and yes jfadich does have a point as much as this answer is helpful

Comment: Ok. I agree and understood. I have updated the code that would give you an array which has values that are empty and another array which have values that are non-empty.

Comment: thank you, i have upvoted and accepted your solution but i have found a more streamlined approach i edited into the post.

Answer (score 0):

If there is possibility that a key is there or not there, it's helpful to have a class/function that can do a check and return. A framework might work something like this:

```
    class Request
        {
            public static function getGet($key=false)
                {
                    if(!empty($key))
                        return (isset($_GET[$key]))? $_GET[$key] : false;

                    return $_GET;
                }

            public static function getPost($key=false)
                {
                    if(!empty($key))
                        return (isset($_POST[$key]))? $_POST[$key] : false;

                    return $_POST;
                }
        }

# Would try to retrieve $_GET['one']
$val1 = Request::getGet('one');
# Would try to retrieve $_POST['two']
$val2 = Request::getPost('two');
```

I wouldn't create dynamic variables, because you still have to check if they are set or whatever. Depending on use and PHP version, you can do:

```
if(Request::getGet('whatever')) {
    # Do something
}
```

Comment: I don't think it needs to be as complicated as this - I was thinking a for loop or foreach loop could do what I needed. I will edit in what I was thinking.

Comment: Yeah, maybe do an example of use. What I have is a good way to return a value and avoid a bunch of `isset` statements to avoid `undefined variable` / `undefined index` errors

Comment: Show how you uses the actual values after your loop thing...I still don't understand why you are wanting to do what you are trying to do. Are you trying to echo something only or what is the final product of those variables??

Comment: Ah ive figured it out i will explain in my post now sorry it is a bit of a strange situation

Comment: You are doing variable variables but the `extract()` is the same thing. Just note, it does not save you time down the line when you have to use the variables. You have to still check if they are set when you go to use them.

Comment: Especially on a `$_GET` because they can be manipulated easily by the user, so just make note of that.

Comment: yep someone mentioned that - i might use post or try the array answer posted earlier.

Comment: Well, a more sophisticated user can still send a POST, so that is only marginally safer, my point is more that you will still need to check if a variable `isset` if you create dynamic variables from a user submitted array.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all of the parameters are provided by checking the keys of `$_GET`

```
$expected_parameters = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
if(count(array_intersect($expected_parameters, array_keys($_GET))) !== count($expected_parameters)) {
    // Failed validation
}
```

That will validate that all the required parameters are present, but it doesn't make sure that they're not empty. I would recommend doing further validation to make sure the parameters are of the required type, but in your question you said this isn't a requirement.

To get the parameters into their own variables you can use `extract()`.

```
extract($_GET)
```

Comment: Yes but I need to know which of the expected paramaters are set - the names of the ones which are set and then preferably have them stored in a variable the same as their name.

Comment: @LucaSarif `extract($_GET)` will take parameters and create new variables based on the key names. so `$_GET['one']` will become `$one`